# Can not increase file upload size and execution time in phpmyadimin in WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using Wampserver (64 bits & PHP 5.5) 2.5. phpmyadmin inside of it is allowing me to import database of max 128mib and execution time is low. I have red all possible tutorials. I have changed php.ini ( both the one that I found from wamp icon and the one located in php folder ), but changes are not reflected to phpmyadmin. I have put upload_max size to 512M and all other stuff, plus I have set `max_execution_time` and other stuff to unlimited. It seems that changes from php.ini are not reflected to phpmyadmin. What the hell is going on? Yes I have restarted wamp, even PC too...

I am using windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Suggest creating a file with `echo phpinfo();` in it so you can see what your current PHP settings actually are; check the "Loaded Configuration File" matches the one you're editing too.   Also you may need to increase  `post_max_size`…  Turn error debugging on.

Comment: I have increased post_max_size.

Comment: phpinfo() says: upload and post sizes are 512M and execution times are -1. Yet phpmyadmin do not recognize that.

Comment: For what it's worth I'd suggest importing your database via the command line instead anyway; those values are much higher than you'd need for the majority of websites (and it would be inadvisable to run a site with them – very easy for the server to run out of memory/resources etc.)

Comment: I am working on huge website, and want to crate local copy of it on my pc, but can not do it coz phpmyadmin in wamp do not work.

Comment: What makes you think that "changes from php.ini are not reflected to phpmyadmin"? Describe the symptom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In WAMPServer 2.5 the PHP limits applied to phpMyAdmin can be found in this file `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

It was done this way so that you do not have to mess with php.ini to increase these parameter which of course would effect every site that you may be developing/maintaining.

This is what the file looks like:

```
# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

So if you want to increase these parameters mentioned at the bottom of the file, do it in this file and it will only effect phpMyAdmin and nothing else.